# How to use FortranCInterface_HEADER to mangle Fortran symbols with cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, fortran

I created a very simple CMakeLists.txt

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.9)

project(MyProject LANGUAGES C CXX Fortran VERSION 1.0.0)

include(FortranCInterface)

FortranCInterface_HEADER(FC.h MACRO_NAMESPACE "FC_")

add_subdirectory(FortranProject)

add_executable(test test.cpp ${CSRCS} ${CXXSRCS} ${FSRCS} ${F90SRCS})
```

All the variables CSRCS, CXXSRCS, FSRCS, and F90SRCS are defined within FortranProject.
I would like to call a Fortran subroutine in test.cpp, let's say foo. From what I understood about the combined use of Fortran and C, the way in which Fortran symbols are mangled depends on the specific compilers used. The CMake function FortranCInterface_HEADER allows us to generate macros based on the compilers to automatically handle the conversion from Fortran to C code.

My FC.h looks like this:

```
#ifndef FC_HEADER_INCLUDED
#define FC_HEADER_INCLUDED

/* Mangling for Fortran global symbols without underscores. */
#define FC_GLOBAL(name,NAME) name##_

/* Mangling for Fortran global symbols with underscores. */
#define FC_GLOBAL_(name,NAME) name##_

/* Mangling for Fortran module symbols without underscores. */
#define FC_MODULE(mod_name,name, mod_NAME,NAME) __##mod_name##_MOD_##name

/* Mangling for Fortran module symbols with underscores. */
#define FC_MODULE_(mod_name,name, mod_NAME,NAME) __##mod_name##_MOD_##name

#endif
```

My questions are the following:

(i) **What's the correct way to include FC.h in test.cpp?** FC.h is only generated after CMake is launched and is placed by default in the build directory. It would seem somehow weird to me to have something like

```
#include <"build_directory"/FC.h>
```

in my test.cpp.

(ii) **How should I call subroutine foo in test.cpp?** In particular, I am confused by the fact that every macro in FC.hpp accepts two arguments, whereas I would expect only one, i.e., the name of the Fortran function to be called.

Comment: Separate to any cmake capability, can you modify the Fortran source (or provide Fortran wrappers)?  There are standard Fortran language features that make interfacing with C (and hence C++) quite straightforward - no need for the programmer to worry about name mangling (and the other calling convention aspects not addressed by the approach in the question).

Comment: I am writing a C++ interface to a Fortran code that I am not developing directly and that is quite involved. Writing Fortran wrappers would maybe be a viable option, although it would essentially require me to create duplicate C++ wrappers afterward to make the code accessible in C++ (for this reason it seems like a cumbersome way to go).

Comment: It is very much worthwhile familiarizing yourself with the Fortran 2003 standard language feature `BIND(C)` and the contents of the intrinsic Fortran module `ISO_C_BINDING` before you finalize your design choices. Exceptions perhaps always exist to any rule, but I consider name mangling approaches to interfacing Fortran to C (and beyond) to be an obsolete and incomplete solution.

Comment: Perhaps you are right, thanks. I will also look into this.